# How can I parse this xml code? I want to get the ball speed values

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<board>
    <ball xVelocity="-2.1" yVelocity="-3.5" />
    <cezmi1 x="1" score="2" /> 
    <gizmos>
        <squareBumper   x="0"  y="2" />
        <squareBumper   x="3"  y="3" />
        <squareBumper  x="5"  y="5" />
        <squareBumper   x="7" y="7" />
        <squareBumper   x="12"  y="12" />   
        <squareBumper   x="7"   y="12" />
        <squareBumper   x="18"  y="10" />
    </gizmos> 
</board>
```

I want to use the speed values like xVelocity and yVelocity in my Example.java

But i have no idea how can i parse it?

Comment: put 4 spaces in front of each line

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it like that.

```
File xmlFile = new File("your.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile); 
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ball");
for (int i= 0; i< nodes.getLength(); i++) { 
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
       Element eElement = (Element)node ;    
       System.out.println("xVelocity : " + eElement.getAttribute("xVelocity"));
       System.out.println("yVelocity: " + eElement.getAttribute("yVelocity"));
    }
}
```

There is an example for [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

Answer (score 0):

This will read multiple ball tags and fetch xVelocity and yVelocity

```
File xmlFile = new File("/path/file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ball");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("xVelocity : " + eElement.getAttribute("xVelocity"));
        System.out.println("yVelocity : " + eElement.getAttribute("yVelocity"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Node nNode = nList.item(temp); //here it want me to cast it, why?

Comment: It should return an element of type node. What JDK version do you have.
refer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

Answer (score 0):

N.B. I didn't read your question very carefully and thought you wanted to pick out the x and y attributes.  But the following example shows how to pull out any of your elements or attributes, including the ones you want, so I've decided toleave the example as is; XPath is very flexible.

You could use JDOM which leverages XPath:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.filter.Filters;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathExpression;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.build("xml/board.xml");

    // search for x attribute
    XPathFactory xpfac = XPathFactory.instance();
    XPathExpression<Attribute> xp = xpfac.compile("//squareBumper/@x", Filters.attribute());
    List<Attribute> results = xp.evaluate(doc);

    Iterator<Attribute> iterator = results.iterator();

    // retreive all x attributes (y is similar)
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Attribute a = iterator.next();
      System.out.println(a.getIntValue());
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

XPath simplifies the parsing (see w3schools for a description of XPath).